# pandas dataframe - add row comment

Tags: python, csv, pandas

How do we add a extra row of str to a pandas dataframe ?

Minimal working example:

```
In [65]: header_list = ['MU', 'Ars', 'THo']
    ...: team =['MU', 'Ars', 'THot']
    ...: w = [1,4,5]
    ...: data = []
    ...: for n, line in enumerate(w, 1):
    ...:     temp = []
    ...:     temp.append(w[n-1])
    ...:     temp.append(w[n-1]+1)
    ...:     temp.append(w[n-1]-1)
    ...:     data.append(temp)
    ...: pd = pandas.DataFrame(data, team, header_list)
```

The dataframe will be saved to a csv file.

```
pd.to_csv(os.path.join(new_directory, base_filename), index=True, sep=',', doublequote=True, escapechar=None,
          decimal='.')
Out[65]: 
      MU  Ars  THo
MU     1    2    0
Ars    4    5    3
THot   5    6    4
```

How can I append an extra row of string to the dataframe, for example: the average is: (numerical value of the average of third column)

Comment: You can create an extra row just the same way you created the original three rows.

Comment: I tried that, got the error as 'Expected list, got str'

Comment: What EXACTLY did you try?

Comment: I tried to append a extra row, data.append(['Average' + w[n]*18]).

Comment: How many elements are in your list:  `['Average' + w[n]*18]`  How many columns are in your dataframe?  If they are not  the same, you will get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas version 0.13, you can use *[loc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement)*

```
d.loc['Avg'] = d.mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use loc as radar suggested. Here is complete sample code to calculate only third column average

```
test_df =pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3))
mean= test_df[2].mean()#2 represents 3rd column name
avg_row = ['The average is' , '' ,mean]
test_df.loc[len(test_df)] =avg_row
test_df

Out[113]: 
                0  1  2
0               0  1  2
1               3  4  5
2               6  7  8
3  The average is     5
```